# Use gcp admin sdk discovery build in cloud function of a service account

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

As of now I am able to access user using below mentioned code in cloud function deployed in service account which has the domain wide delegation. But i am using service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file from a credential file but i do not want to hard code the credentials which is not the correct approach. Please let me know if there is a way to use without passing credential.

If i do not use credentials inside build then I get 403.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service-account-bc07yg1386.json'


credentials_org = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, subject="admin@domain.com")

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials_org)

results = service.users().get(userKey=user_email).execute()
```

Comment: Hi there, would you mind being more explicit about what are you trying to achieve in this situation? What do you mean by "without passing credential"? @SharathKirani

Comment: As service account has all the necessary permissions and my cloud function is deployed in the service account. So there should be no need of any service account credentials.
As i have to pass scope and subject to the credential object, there is no way to pass these scope to googleapiclient.discovery.build. If i do not pass scope and subject(Impersonating admin) to build. I will get 403.

Please let me know if you require any further details.
thanks

Comment: So essentially you do not want to include the credentials and the scopes when building the service? SharathKirani

Comment: Yes, if it is possible to do so.
Else, How to set the scope and subject to build object, so that i get 200 response.

If there is any way out to get the users from this api, happy to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by "to build object"? Moreover, are you getting the 200 code when doing the request now?

Comment: Build object means ``

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials_org)```

Status code 200 instead of 403

Answer (score 0):

When using a service account, you **need** to use the credentials in order to authenticate the request.

Furthermore, you can instantiate an **Admin SDK Directory service object** by using the below code, taken from the [Performing G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object):

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<some-id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '/path/to/<public_key_fingerprint>-privatekey.p12'

def create_directory_service(user_email):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH,
        'notasecret',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'])
    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)
    return build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

### Note

The Python version uses a *P12-formatted key file* which can be generated when going to the corresponding *Google Cloud Project*, selecting the *Admin SDK* and then *Credentials*:

[image: create P12 key file]

#### Reference

- [Instantiate an Admin SDK Directory service object](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object).